# Wordpress Website with Login system

Tags: functions, session, wp-blog-header.php

I am new to WordPress but have been developing in PHP (CI specially). I stumbled into problem when I have to integrate a website developed in CI with a WordPress website. This wordpress component is another website that is extension of current site (You know Clients make you do weird stuffs at times!) . The customers have a code provided by my client which they will use in a section of CI segment, and if the code matches, then the customers are to be redirected to the wordpress site. The customer should not be directly able to access the wordpress site without using the codes i.e.  directly  through the url!

From my research I have found that header.php is included everytime in wordpress, so I am planning to , initiate a php native session (as CI uses its own) if the code matches, then check the session in the header.php file.

What I do not understand is how can I modify this header file to do so? I mean, I will be needing custom functions right?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can create function in theme's functions.php file. WordPress provide lots of hooks for that. And check if certain conditions to use wp_redirect for redirecting users accordingly.

Comment: Could you please provide me some code hints, I am not very familiar with hooks

Comment: Added some code. It executes before WordPress website starts loading. So you can safely check for access.

Comment: This means that, I need not do any thing in the header.php file right? I just have to check if the session exists in the if() condition below? One last thing Robert, can native php  session be started at the start of functions.php file? Thanks a lot mate!, I wish I could upvote you for your support!

Comment: Well, functions.php file load before any theme file so you can use this to check your session. Yes you can start session in functions.php. Check edit in my answer. If you cannot upvote and feel my answer helped you, then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a simple example. init action loads before loading WordPress website. So we can use it to check some special conditions for allowing access to users.

You should use this in functions.php

```
function user_custom_redirect() {
    if ( 'something' === 'something else' ) {
        // let user view WordPress website
    } else {
        // redirect them to google.com
        // can be set to redirect back to request URL also.
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.google.com', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'user_custom_redirect' );
```

**EDIT: Session**

You can also start session like this.

```
function start_init_session() {
    session_start();
}

add_action( 'init', 'kana_init_session', 1 );
```

Comment: Please, this is not a theme job. **Never** put user access control into theme files.

Comment: Is that because if in case the theme is changed by the user, the authentication will not be done? So in which functions.php file am I supposed to make these changes?

Comment: He is referring to plugins. You can create a plugin for authenticating your users.